# Can't place image object with other HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can't place an image object on the DOM with other HTML elements. For example:

```
$('#preview> tbody:last')[0].appendChild('<tr><td>' + image + '</td></tr>');
```

This will not work. Nothing shows up. However, when I only use the image, it shows up on the screen:

```
$('#preview> tbody:last')[0].appendChild(image);
```

Why won't this work? It seems to me like it should work either way. I tried using just `append` but then nothing worked - the image by itself **or** with the other elements.

**Full Code Bit**

```
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = event.target.result;
        image.width = 50;
        $('#preview> tbody:last')[0].appendChild(image);
    };
```

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that `appendChild()` expects a node (or node-reference), not a HTML string.

To use a string, use `innerHTML()` (but bear in mind that this rewrites/overwrites any existing HTML in the relevant element (and so loses any events bound to the existing HTML).

I've not tested, but why not stick with jQuery (despite the somewhat verbose approach), since you're using it anyway:

```
$('#preview> tbody:last').append('<tr><td></td></tr>').find('td').append(image);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EeamB/).

Reference:

- [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating a DOM object and a string in your first example. In your second example, you're only putting the DOM object into the table - it shouldn't work because you're missing row and column, but the browser must just be forgiving.

I'd say either build the image as an HTML string and append it raw, or build the row and column as DOM objects, but you'll have to be consistent.